# Price Tag for electronics Store in HTML **EDIT**(1)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am a student at an University specialized in information technologies. I have been learning C++ and C# for the past two years, and recently I made a bet with my uncle about a html task. If I manage to successfully complete the task and get it working, I'll get a job vacancy in his firm for the summer. If i don't complete, then I'll have to find a job for the summer.

The task is to make a template for a price tag for an electronics store in HTML. I will provide some graphical information below. 
[image: Here is the "skeleton" of the template]

Each number in the fields corresponds to some font, font size, content, etc.
The task is to create a price tag like this in html, a template to be specific and make it possible to resize the thing and print it.

The problem is thath I have never used HTML in a way like this. The only time I used HTML was for some silly websites I made when I was bored.
I would appriciate if someone could give me some directions, some advice or some references to something simmilar so that I can begin this mad process.
How would i go to start about this project? I know that i need to learn and use CSS and some scripting languages like php or javascript. I would appriciate everything you throw at me.

Thanks in advance. I just need a little kick to get started because I have searched all over the web with no success.

EDIT: So here is my try at this. I've made the boxes, but now im stuck with some blocks that won't stay in line (block 5-10;)
How do i make block 5,6,7 on one line and 8,9,10 on another?
PS: made this in codepen, link below code.
HTML:

```
<div class="mainblock">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="spacing"></div>

  <div class="middle">
    <div class="four"></div>
    <div class="five"></div>
    <div class="six"></div>
    <div class="seven"></div>
    <div class="eight"></div>
    <div class="nine"></div>
    <div class="ten"></div>

  </div>

  <div class="spacing"></div>

  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.top,.middle,.bottom{
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: blue;
  margin: 0mm;
}
.clearfix{
  clear: both;
}
.spacing{
  height: 1mm;
  width: 91mm;
}
.mainblock{
  width: 91mm;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  padding-left: 7mm;
  padding-right: 7mm;
  padding-bottom: 7mm;
  padding-top: 27mm;
}

.top{
  width: 91mm;
  height: 7mm;
}
.middle{
  width: 91mm;
  height: 16mm;  
}
.bottom{
  width: 91mm;
  height: 16mm;
}

.one,.two,.three,.four,.five,.six,.seven,.eight,.nine,.ten,.eleven,.twelve,.thirteen,.fourteen,.fifthteen,.sixthteen,.seventhteen,.eighthteen,.ninethteen,.twenty,.twentyone,.twentytwo,.twentythree,.twentyfour{
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: green;
}
.one{
  width: 67mm;
  height: 7mm;
  float: left;
}
.two{
  width: 24mm;
  height: 3.5mm;
  margin-left:67mm;
}
.three{
  width: 24mm;
  height: 3.5mm;
  margin-left:67mm
}
.four{
  width: 65mm;
  height: 16mm;
  float: left;
}
.five,.six,.seven,.eight,.nine,.ten{
  width: 8mm;
  height: 8mm;
}
.five,.eight{
  margin-left: 67mm;
}
.six,.nine{
  margin-left: 75mm;
}
.seven,.ten{
  margin-left: 83mm;
}
```

Codepen rite [HERE](https://codepen.io/milkslayer/pen/ZKxxgg/)

Comment: I don't really know how to do this but I remember my company having html for the site and separate html for the print (I think).

Comment: I'm in agreement with Paulie_D.  It's highly unlikely that you have searched ***all over the web*** and found nothing worth trying.  What have you tried thus far?  Can you post some code that you've tested that didn't work the way you expected?  Do you need the price tag HTML to be generated locally or on the server?  This would help decide if Javascript or PHP/other server language would be best to learn first assuming you cannot learn both (which would be my recommendation).

Comment: Take note that width, height, padding, margin, and border sizes stack on top of each other. Another way to say it, they're exclusive when adding up the full space that an element will take on the screen. I.E.: `divWidth = width + marginLeft + paddingLeft + marginRight + paddingRight`. However, you can get around some of this with `box-sizing: border-box;` in your CSS.

Comment: Instead of editing, I would create another question. It'll get too confusing if you edit for every new problem you encounter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to create nice printouts but it sounds like you need to learn html, css, and javascript. HTML is the bones. CSS is the skin and makeup (styling). Javascript (and jQuery) is the way to dynamically change whatever values you need changed.

For html, I like to think in terms of boxes. Just, boxes inside of boxes. This image is not complete but it gives the essence of the idea. The blue is the overall divs and the green are divs inside the blue.

```
<div class="blue float-left">
  <div class="green float-left"></div>
  <div class="green float-left"></div>
  <div class="clearfix></div>
</div>
<div class="blue float-left">
  <div class="green float-left"></div>
  <div class="green float-left"></div>
  <div class="green float-left"></div>
  <div class="clearfix></div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix></div>
```

[image]

The class attribute is used for styling. There's a lot of ideas here but it'll at least give you a start. You may want to checkout something like [purecss](https://purecss.io/) instead of writing your own css.

For javascript, checkout the [MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/). Use search terms like, "javascript mdn get element". You may be interested in [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) or javascript methods like `document.getElementById`.

Good luck!